# Passing more parameters in Ajax_pagination in CodeIgniter 3.0

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I am using `Ajax_pagination` library in CodeIgniter 3.0.The pagination is working fine.Now i want to pass more parameters with page itself.

For Example I have a page where User select Country and Category.Now i want to show data with pagination.Here is my code.

```
function ajaxPaginationData()
  {
 $page = $this->input->post('page');
    if(!$page){
        $offset = 0;
    }else{
        $offset = $page;
    }
    $totalRec = count($this->post->getRows());

    //pagination configuration
    $config['first_link']  = 'First';
    $config['div']         = 'postList'; //parent div tag id
    $config['base_url']    = base_url().'index.php/posts/ajaxPaginationData';
    $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
    $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;
    $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['posts'] = $this->post->getRows(array('start'=>$offset,'limit'=>$this->perPage));
   $this->load->view('posts/ajax-pagination-data', $data, false);
}
```

Here is my pagination html

```
<div class="pagination">Showing 1 to 5 of 8 | &nbsp;<b>1</b>&nbsp;<a onclick="$.post('http://localhost:8080/ajax/index.php/posts/ajaxPaginationData/5', {'page' : 5}, function(data){
                $('#postList').html(data); }); return false;" href="javascript:void(0);">2</a>&nbsp;<a onclick="$.post('http://localhost:8080/ajax/index.php/posts/ajaxPaginationData/5', {'page' : 5}, function(data){
                $('#postList').html(data); }); return false;" href="javascript:void(0);">&gt;</a>&nbsp;</div>
```

Now On Change of country dropdown I want to get list with that Id

```
<select id="country">
<option value="0">select</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">UK</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the value of your dropdown in function

```
function ajaxPaginationData($country)
  {
 $page = $this->input->post('page');
    if(!$page){
        $offset = 0;
    }else{
        $offset = $page;
    }
    $totalRec = count($this->post->getRows());

    //pagination configuration
    $config['first_link']  = 'First';
    $config['div']         = 'postList'; //parent div tag id
    $config['base_url']    = base_url().'index.php/posts/ajaxPaginationData';
    $config['total_rows']  = $totalRec;
    $config['per_page']    = $this->perPage;
    $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['posts'] = $this->post->getRows(array('start'=>$offset,'limit'=>$this->perPage));
   $this->load->view('posts/ajax-pagination-data', $data, false);
}
```

And use $country to select the data from table with where condition.

for more on pagination try this http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-do-pagination-in-codeigniter/